# WCF service response shows &amp; instead of & when called from Java application

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, ampersand

I have a WCF service which returns a class object and has a string property in it.
When I call the WCF service from Java code I get the response(Response will be an URL always).

The & tags on the response are seen as & on the Java app.

Can anyone guide me on the same?

Answer (score 1):

This is because special characters are encoded in URL. It doesn't matter if the client is a .NET or a Java application

You could use Apache Commons [StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) to decode the string in Java.

In .Net, you can use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) to decode it.